# Brush Tool keeps changing whenever I try to use (Adobe Illustrator CC 2015)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cc-2015

Currently, I'm facing this kind of problem. When I tried to use the brush it keeps changing its attribute randomly. I've read some thread that says, I need to uncheck the New Art Basic Appearance located on Appearance panel. Already tried that but not working.

**My preferred brush attribute is**

[image]

**But the attribute keeps changing after using the brush.**
[image]

Comment: Related and helpful https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/109770/63979

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to draw freehand with the Brush, but want a "basic" setting. This is not possible, because that "basic" setting doesn't work with the Brush tool.

Use the Pencil tool instead if you want to draw freehand, with a "basic" stroke.

The interface is a bit confusing in regards to this, and Adobe probably needs to do some work to address the problem of "basic" still being a selectable option when using the Brush, despite the fact it won't work with the Brush tool. Of course, Illustrator is not user friendly (never has been in fact), but I suppose that's the cross we have to bear until Adobe improves it.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a line with the brush tool.

Select All (Ctrl+A)

Then go to Object----Transform----Transform Each

Click the checkbox for Enable Scale Stroke and Effects

click Ok.

Now it should work for you.